# Watch LESS file with multiple imports, only compile single file

Tags: less, watch

I'm trying to find a good solution to watch a single LESS file with a bunch of imports for changes (including changes in the imported files, but only compiling the main file).

I've split my LESS into separate files as "modules" to keep it little bit more manageable and the main LESS file is just a bunch of imports. However every solution I've looked up for watching for changes instead of having to compile manually every time, either compiles every LESS file in the directory or doesn't recognize changes in the imported files.

So I'm looking for a solution that could watch changes in all LESS files, but in case of changes would only compile the main LESS file. If someone has done something like this before, it would help me a lot instead of having to make something from scratch.

**Update:**
I found this https://github.com/jonycheung/Dead-Simple-LESS-Watch-Compiler. By default it checks and compiles every less file in a directory. Was pretty simple to modify to watch all less files and compile only the main file when changes are detected.

Answer (score 3):

LESS 1.3.1 has a new function called `@import-once`. Instead of `@import`, use `@import-once`.

It's not well documented, but here's the [changelog](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) and [issue, discussion, more](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/issues/212)

Comment: If you read through the comments at the [link](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/issues/212) Paul Armstrong mentions here, you'll see that now (as of Aug 2013) the standard LESS import behaviour is to import each file only once. You no longer have to use the alternate @import-once syntax, which is only retained for backward compatibility. There seems to be a delay in the implementation in lessphp, since the [pull-request](https://github.com/leafo/lessphp/pull/435) is still pending. In lessc and node, though, this is now the default behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're using Coffeescript, but since Less is dependent on Node you've got that installed.  I created the following Cakefile which should be very easy to translate to a plain javascript file.  It should also be very easy to modify for multiple files.

```
option '-c', '--lessFile [main Less Filename]', 'The single file to be compiled into the stylesheet, it should import any files it needs'

task 'watch-less', 'Compile Less scripts on the fly during Development', (opts) ->
  less = options.less

  watchers = []

  compile = () ->
    w.close() for w in watchers
    exec "lessc #{less} #{less.replace /\.less$/, ".css"}"
    watch()

  watch = () ->
    exec "lessc -M #{less} -", (err, stdout, stderr) ->
      throw new Error err if err
      watchers = (fs.watch(f, compile) for f in stdout.trim().split(' ').splice(1))

  compile()
```

Notices and Disclaimers:

- Other than less no external dependencies.
- Beware the `fs.watch`, not cross-platform

Comment: this could be made even better by using the `less` API